# Set div height of its contents with position: absolute

Tags: css, position, slideshow

what I am trying to accomplish is the following:

```
<div>
    <div class="img"><img src=""></div>
    <div class="img"><img src=""></div>
    <div class="img"><img src=""></div>
</div>
```

the divs containing the images will be used in a slideshow so they need to be positioned one on top of the other, with the first one showing and the others hidden.

When I set position:absolute to the divs though, the external div's height shrinks and destroys the whole layout. Any tips on how to to fix that?

EDIT: HTML structure is not negotiable.

Comment: Explicitly define the `div`'s dimensions.

Comment: can't since the images sizes may vary.

Comment: Why don't you use a single div and single image tag. You can change the src attribute of the image when ever you want either on click or after a particular amount of time by a javascript function.

Comment: This is the way it's produced via the CMS, and altering that would be a huge pain, that's why I stated the question this way, please don't propose other HTML structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up setting the div's height with JQuery according to it's content. Just needed to add one line of code in the loop. Case closed.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is wrong, the way to do this is not to have the divs stacked on top of each other with absolute positioning.  Set the css on the last two divs to display:none. When you want to move to the next image, set the image as display:block.   (example shown uses JQuery)

```
$("div#image2").show();
```

and then hide the other two

```
$("div#image2").siblings().hide();
```

You'll need to add an id attribute so you can uniquely select your images.

Comment: They *are* hidden, and I *do* know how to use show and hide. Thing is if I don't position them one on top of the other they are stacked vertically. And since i am not using .show and .hide but fadeIn and fadeOut, the images must be positioned absolutely beforehand

Comment: your approach works with a crude show/hide slideshow but if you wanna use fadein and out, divs must be one on top of the other.